# Apache - Require all denied HTTP status code

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am using Apache 2.4 and I am blocking an access to a specific sub-domain for everyone except one IP address.

**.htaccess:**

```
Require all denied
Require ip 111.222.333.444
```

This returns an "403 Forbidden" status code.

How can I make it return "404 Not Found"?

No-one from outside should know about the existence of this sub-domain.
So, from external point of view, I would like to make it "invisible".
Thus, everyone who goes to that domain, will receive 404 as if it does not exist.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^111.222.333.444$
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]
```

However, this doesn't really *hide* the fact a sub-domain exists. It returns a page not found, which is not the same thing. Presumably your subdomain still has a DNS entry, so it can be looked up.

I would also question the need to do this, `403` exists for a reason and I can't see why not to return it. Whether or not you return a `403` or a `404`, the site still exists so I don't know what you're trying to achieve. No method would be enough to deter a determined hacker, and it's probably a safer method to deny an ip at server level rather than trying to obfuscate via http redirects.

Answer (score 1):

Using mod _rewrite may not be as elegant as simply denying the ip but it should get it done as follows.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=111.222.333.444
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [R=404]
```